# Value of the probability density function at a certain point.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

The PDF $f(x)$ of a continuous random variable $X$ is defined to be a continuous function with the required properties. How is the value of $f(x)$ interpreted at a ‘point’, say $a$? Is there any analogy between $f(a)$ and $m(a)$ [the probability mass function-al value of some (discrete)random variable at a given point].

**Note:** The value $f(a)$ is given to be the value of the derivative of the CDF at $a$. But, as evident from the discrete case, thus analogously, isn’t the PDF more fundamental than the CDF? I mean the CDF is defined to be the *integral* of a certain continuous function, which is to be called the PDF. So doesn’t this fall back into a cycle? (Loosely)*The CDF is the integral of the PDF, which is the derivative of the CDF*. (There are questions here like this previously asked, and adequately answered, but the doubt persists)

Is there a clearer picture of what the value of the PDF is to be interpreted as at a particular point?

Comment: It's not circular.  A cumulative distribution function is *not* defined by being an integral; but rather by being a probability measure.  There are CDF that do not have derivatives.

Comment: According to the text, they have derivatives which are piecewise continuous...say for example the CDF of the Uniform Distribution. Moreover, doesn’t the derivative thing follow immediately due to the fundamental theorem of calculus?

Comment: For continuous random variables, they are, but not all random variables are such. The definition is for discrete variables as well.

Comment: Kind of, but my question was that since the CDF $F(x)$ is described to be the integral of the density function, and the density function here is, loosely, the derivative of the CDF, isn’t this getting circular? What is the way out? What does the PDF mean, and more specifically what does the value of $f(x)$ at $x=a$ tell us exactly?

Comment: The CDF comes first in this chicken-and-the-egg scenario. The CDF is defined as $F(x)=P(X\le x)$, without referencing the PDF at all. Everything has a CDF, but not everything has a CDF, so the CDF must be more fundamental. $\tag*{}$The PDF is defined as the derivative of the CDF (provided this derivative exists, and excepting weird special cases like the Cantor distribution). In that sense the PDF has no deeper meaning. Still, if you allow yourself to be imprecise, then there is a lot of intuition that can be gleaned from the PDF, as mentioned in the answers to the linked question.